# ошибка java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: android

Задача простая. Чтобы один из элементов карточки заполнялся рандомным цветом и при клике на эту карточку открывалась активити, тулбар которой заполнялся бы тем же цветом. Но вылезает ошибка `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer` Один тип не может быть приведен к другому. Меняла приведение типов, ничего не помогает. Ошибка именно при передачи цвета в тулбар, т.к. без этого код работает. Помогите разобраться.

В onCreateViewHolder устанавливаю элементу рандомный цвет

```
 int[] androidColors = view.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.androidColors);
    int randomAndroidColor = androidColors[new Random().nextInt(androidColors.length)];
    if (frameLayout != null) {
        frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(randomAndroidColor);
    }
```

В классе активити, показывающей подробное описание:

```
public static final String EXTRA_POEM_ID = "poem_id";
public static final String EXTRA_COLOR = "random_android_color";
private long poemId;
private int randomAndroidColor;
poemId = getIntent().getLongExtra(EXTRA_POEM_ID, -1);
randomAndroidColor = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_COLOR, 0);
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(randomAndroidColor);
```

В адаптере создан интерфейс:

```
 itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                long poemId = (Long) v.getTag();
                int randomAndroidColor = (int) v.getTag();
                onPoemClickListener.onPoemClick(poemId, randomAndroidColor);

                }
        });
    }
}

public interface OnPoemClickListener {
    void onPoemClick(long poemId, int randomAndroidColor);

}
```

и код фрагмента, где располагается список с карточками

```
  private final PoemsAdapter.OnPoemClickListener onPoemClickListener = new PoemsAdapter.OnPoemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPoemClick(long poemId, int randomAndroidColor) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ReadActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(ReadActivity.EXTRA_POEM_ID, poemId);
        intent.putExtra(ReadActivity.EXTRA_COLOR, randomAndroidColor);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В методе onClick нужно было не тег устанавливать (т.к. тег должен быть один), а получить сгенерированный рандомный цвет. Итого весь код ViewHolder-а

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    .....
    FrameLayout frameLayout;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        ........
        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);

        int[] androidColors = itemView.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.androidColors);
        int randomAndroidColor = androidColors[new Random().nextInt(androidColors.length)];
        frameLayout.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(randomAndroidColor));

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                long poemId = (Long) v.getTag();

                ColorDrawable viewColor = (ColorDrawable) frameLayout.getBackground();
                int randomAndroidColor = viewColor.getColor();
                onPoemClickListener.onPoemClick(poemId, randomAndroidColor);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте:

```
private long randomAndroidColor;
randomAndroidColor = getIntent().getLongExtra(EXTRA_COLOR, 0L);
```

Comment: Если randomAndroidColor сделать лонговым, то в дальнейшем когда устанавливаю этот цвет в тулбар выпадает ошибка, т.к. по документации цвета должны быть в int

Comment: Ну а так ошибка, которая в вопросе пропадает, если сделать как вы написали. Но цвет не установить. Таким способом делаю getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(String.valueOf(randomAndroidColor))));

Comment: что-то я не понял, таким способом вы меняете объект Drawable, new ColorDrawable действительно принимает на вход int, но setBackgroundColor принимает на вход long.